# JSON and common information model

Tags: xml, json, jsonschema

Let's assume a common information model exists. I want to ensure that JSON based services implemented by different projects using different technologies (Java, .NET, you name it) all represent their data consistently with this model.

Using XML, I would create a bunch of XSD. How to proceed with JSON? Has anyone been using JSON schema (http://json-schema.org/) for that purpose? Or Should I keep using XML? (This is not a JSON vs XML question...)

Comment: Does none of the 8 "related" questions to the right help you? (Or any of the many other JSON and JSON Schema tagged questions here?)

Comment: Well, someone has for sure solved this before but I cannot find anything matching this on stackoverflow or somewhere else...